# RxJs Handle error when there is another request inside map

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have service for login and use it in the following way:

```
// LoginComponent
    this.authService.loginDb(credentials)
          .subscribe(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            },
            (error) => {
              this.errorMessage = error.description
            });

//auth.service
public loginDb(credentials: Credentials): Observable <any> {
    //make call to third party API
    return this.auth0.client.login({
            ...
        })
        .map((resp) => {
            // here decode token and then make another request to my server for saving user
            this.token = <Token> this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(resp.idToken);
            return this.userService.createOrUpdateUser(this.token)
                .subscribe(() => {
                    this.localStorageService.set('token', resp.idToken);
                    this.localStorageService.set('decoded_token', this.token);
                    this.loggedIn = true;
                })
        })
}
```

The problem is, for example there is error on my server and `this.userService.createOrUpdateUser` is failed then `error` wont handle this in `LoginComponent`. So, I want `error` to handle for inner request too. Moreover, I see that `subscribe` is called before second request is finished.

I believe there is some operator in rxjs for this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace `map()` with `concatMap()` it'll wait until its inner Observable completes. Also if the inner Observable emits an error it'll be propagated down the chain.

In general try to avoid nesting `subscribe()` calls.

```
public loginDb(credentials: Credentials): Observable <any> {
    //make call to third party API
    return this.auth0.client.login({
            ...
        })
        .do(resp => {
            this.localStorageService.set('token', resp.idToken);
            this.localStorageService.set('decoded_token', this.token);
        })
        .concatMap((resp) => {
            // here decode token and then make another request to my server for saving user
            this.token = <Token> this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(resp.idToken);
            return this.userService.createOrUpdateUser(this.token);
        })
        .do(() => {
            this.loggedIn = true;
        });
}
```

A used two `do()`s to perform some side-effects but maybe in you particular use case you won't need them or use them in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: do has been replaced by tap